# How to check if JsonObject has specified String

Tags: android, json

Ok so I'm dealing with a Json Object that is composed of menus and sub menus.
The things is that sometimes there isn't any sub menus.

So how to check if the JsonObject has a specified String (Submenu)?
For the moment it just throws a JsonExeption.

Thx!

Comment: Can you supply an example JSON to help us know what you're trying to parse?

Answer (score 1):

It has a method for check ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String))):

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.has(your_string);
```

Quote:

> public boolean has (String name)
>
> Returns true if this object has a mapping for name. The mapping may be NULL.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the specification? Preferably with the section you are referencing cited in your answer.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)